# VPSにてuwsgiのインストールができません

Tags: python, centos, uwsgi

DTIのServersMan VPSを使用しています。
OSはCentOS6です。

PythonのWSGIミドルウェアであるuWSGIをeasy_installを使って入れようとしてますが、
うまく入りません。

コマンドは下記をしています。

```
#easy_install uwsgi
```

初めはCコンパイラが必要とのことでgccを入れましたが、
それでも大量のエラーがでてしまい、完了しません。

```
[thread 1][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
[thread 0][gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyutils.o
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:4:25: error: frameobject.h: No such file or directory
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:59: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:60: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

（中略）

```
plugins/python/pyutils.c:386: error: implicit declaration of function ‘PyDict_SetItemString’
plugins/python/pyutils.c:386: error: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromString’
```

上記のようなエラーが発生します。

pipで試しても同じ状況です。

WEBで調べて見てもみなさんシンプルにトラブル無くインストールができているようで
対策がわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: uwsgiのインストールページをしっかり読んでいませんでした。
無事にインストールできました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のコマンドを実行してから、再度`easy_install`または`pip`でインストールをやってみてください。
`python`はインストール済みだと思われますので、二行目は不要だと思いますが一応。

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install python
yum install python-devel
```

参考:　[Installing uWSGI, installing-from-source — uWSGI 2.0 documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Install.html#installing-from-source)